# Unable to move print spooler on Windows Server 2008R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, print-server

I have installed the Print and Document Services role on a fresh Windows Server 2008R2 Enterprise box that is fully updated and on my domain. I have a second hard drive "E:\" that I would like to have my spooler on.

Whenever I change the spooler folder in the print server properties to "E:\" and click "Ok" it gives me the error "Unable to save server settings. Access is denied." There is no event log generated.

I am using a Domain Admin account and UAC is disabled on the server. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

You can only add a directory location.  Create e:\spool, then set the path.